# Why is the command in /proc/XXX/cmdline truncated but not the arguments

Tags: linux, process

I have a small bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $(cat /proc/$PPID/cmdline | strings -1)
```

I call this script from a perl script which is run through nginx.

```
my $output_string = `/tmp/my_bash_script.sh`;
print $output_string;
```

When I load this in a browser, the result is something like:

```
/mnt/my_working_d -d /etc/my_httpd -f /etc/my_httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

The location of the perl script is indeed somewhere in /mnt/my_working_directory/.... but why is this truncated and is there anyting I can do to log the whole command. I don't think the cmdline limit of 4k characters (?) which seems hardcoded in the kernel applies here.

Comment: post the output of command "cat /proc/$PPID/cmdline | strings -1"  as I dont see any reason of just one arg to be truncated as length of "/etc/my_httpd/conf/httpd.conf" is greater then "/mnt/my_working_d", it could be that arguments are "/mnt/my_working_d -d /etc/my_httpd -f /etc/my_httpd/conf/httpd.conf"

Comment: Obviously if I run the bash script by hand displays '-bash'